# Simple undirected unlabelled graph in JGraphT doesn't work? What is the edgeClass parameter?

Tags: java, reflection, graph, jgrapht

I want to make a simple undirected unlabelled (edges aren't labelled) graph `A<->B` in JGraphT 0.8.3:

```
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge;
import org.jgrapht.graph.SimpleGraph;

class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleGraph<String, String> sg =
            new SimpleGraph<String, String>(String.class);
        sg.addVertex("A");
        sg.addVertex("B");
        sg.addEdge("A", "B");
        System.out.println("edges of A: " + sg.edgesOf("A"));
        System.out.println("edges of B: " + sg.edgesOf("B"));
    }
}
```

I get this output:

```
$ java -cp 'jgrapht-jdk1.6.jar:.' A
edges of A: []
edges of B: []
```

Why are the sets of edges of vertices `A` and `B` empty? Also what is the class parameter of `SimpleGraph` for? It seems to be the type of edges, but since my edges here are unlabelled, surely it doesn't matter? All the graph classes seem to take the class of the edge (`edgeClass`) as a parameter. I can't find where in the documentation `edgeClass` is described.

---

I found if I label the edge (change the `addEdge` line to `sg.addEdge("A", "B", "an_edge");`) then it works... but I don't want to label the edges...

```
$ java -cp 'jgrapht-jdk1.6.jar:.' A
edges of A: [an_edge]
edges of B: [an_edge]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to label the edges. the problem in your approach is that you tell the graph to use String as edge type. A proper std. way of doing things would be:

```
    SimpleGraph<String, DefaultEdge> sg = new SimpleGraph<String, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
    sg.addVertex("A");
    sg.addVertex("B");
    sg.addVertex("C");
    sg.addEdge("A", "B");
    sg.addEdge("B", "C");
    System.out.println("graph: " + sg.toString());
    System.out.println("edges of A: " + sg.edgesOf("A"));
    System.out.println("edges of B: " + sg.edgesOf("B"));
```

this will give you the following output:

```
graph: ([A, B, C], [{A,B}, {B,C}])
edges of A: [(A : B)]
edges of B: [(A : B), (B : C)]
```

So to fix the problem it is necessary to switch your edge class to DefaultEdge as shown in the code.

Comment: But what is the edge class even for? Why does it break with `String`? I also noticed I can make the edge class be `Object`, and it will also work. I've searched the internet and the documentation quite a lot and found it surprising that I can't find anyone explaining what it's for.

Comment: a) Edge class is useful when you want to set weights to your edges (e.g. in travel context) or when you want to give an edge a type (e.g. ontologies) If you didn't need these feats, the DefaultEdge is the proper answer.
b) It didn't break with String, without a label it simply can't identify it. graph.toString() shows the edge even with String edges it looks like: graph: ([A, B, C], [={A,B}]). So the empty string is the edge identifier. If you insert another edge without label, this won't be set because empty string is already there and insertion works with equals and hashcode method.

Comment: oh. so it's using reflection to call the default constructor of `String`?

Comment: yes, that is right. When creating a new edge, the underlying function calls: edgeClass.newInstance();